# Why is wp_list_categories () automatically inserted at the top of the page?

Tags: php, wordpress

The **wp_list_categories()** function is said to return a string. However, it does not return anything and activates the output of the list of categories in another place.

The content on the page is generated as follows

```
function build_index_posts(...){
  $html = '';
  $html.= '<div class="one">';
  $html.= '<h1>'.$header_arr['title'].'</h1>';
  $html.= '</div>';

  return $html;
}
```

I am trying to output a block with a list of child categories, but it is inserted not in the specified place, but at the very beginning of the page.

```
   function build_index_posts(...){
      $html = '';
      $html.= '<div class="one">';
      $html.= '<h1>'.$header_arr['title'].'</h1>';
      $html.= '</div>';
    
      $category = get_queried_object();
      $category_id = $category->term_id;
                    
        $li_args = array(
         'child_of' => $category_id,
         'depth' => 1, 
         'style' => 'none',  
         'hide_empty' => 0,  
         'orderby'      => 'name',  
         'show_count'   => 0,  
         'pad_counts'   => 0, 
         'hierarchical' => 1,  
         'title_li'     => ''  
        );

        $cat_list = wp_list_categories($li_args);
        $cat_list = str_replace('<br>', '', $cat_list);
        
        $html.= '<div style="display: none">';
        $html.= $cat_list;  // NULL ?? 
        $html.= '</div>';

      return $html;
    }
```

**How can I insert a list of categories in the appropriate block?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to use `wp_list_categories()` - the way you are using it will immediately output the list where it is called in the code - this is why you are seeing it at the top of the page.

If you want to get a list of the categories as a variable, you need to pass include the `echo` argument with a value of `false` (it defaults to true):

```
$li_args = array(
     'echo' => false,
      /* the rest of your args */
);

// now you can save the list in a variable.
$cat_list = wp_list_categories($li_args);
```

**Reference**: [Wordpress Code Reference for `wp_list_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/)

Comment: Taking this opportunity, you can ask why it doesn't work str_replace("<br>", "", $cat_list); ? Although, so replaces str_replace("br", "", $cat_list); thank you in advance

Comment: Although, this is just a link separator, I just specified 'separator'=> ", and solved the problem. But I still wonder why str_replace doesn't replace <br> because of parentheses

Comment: @VanilJS Difficult to know for sure without seeing it, but the most likely reason would be that it was using `<br />`  (which is the correct syntax) and not `<br>`. Did you check it in the inspector to see what it was using?